# Jinja2, Using map with format filter, what is the trick?

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

New comer in Jinja2, I'm fan of map feature to play with list. So my intention is to use map filter to format a python list. I read Jinja2 documentation that map filter can be use to *"Applies a filter on a sequence of objects"*. But I don't find a clear way to pass a parameter to format filter when its use inside map filter in Jinja2 template

example:
python data:

```
colors = [ 'blue', 'red', 'green']
```

Jinja2 template (just reformat python list into scheme style)
wanted result is `colors=(list "blue" "red" "green")`

So I start with following template line but its not obvious where to place the format parameter `'"%s"'`, the first parameter of map is the filter name only...

```
colors=(list {{ colors | map('format') | join(" ")}})
```

I read some workaround some of you

- use ansible filter regexp-replace to do the job
- other use for structure in Jinja2 template

`{% for color in colors %} "{{color}}" {% endfor %}`

But I just need to know if I miss something to do that with map and format filter ?

Thanks by advance for your answer
regards

For Information, I use python 3.6.3 and Jinja2 3.0.1

Comment: I would use `map`  before sending data to `Jinja`

Comment: you could use `" "` in `join( '" "' )` like `list "{{ colors | join('" "')}}"`

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't answer how to use `map` but I would do it without `map` using `'" "'` in `join`, and putting string in `" "`.

```
import jinja2

e = jinja2.Environment()

colors = [ 'blue', 'red', 'green']

t = e.from_string('colors=(list "{{ colors | join(\'" "\')}}")')
result = t.render({'colors': colors})
print(result)
```

Result:

```
'colors=(list "blue" "red" "green")'
```

---

**EDIT:**

If I would have to use `map` then I would use it before sending to template

```
import jinja2

e = jinja2.Environment()

colors = [ 'blue', 'red', 'green']

#colors = list(map('"{}"'.format, colors))
#print(colors)

colors = map('"{}"'.format, colors)

t = e.from_string('colors=(list {{ colors | join(" ")}})')
result = t.render({'colors': colors})
print(result)
```

Even documentation for [format](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.format) in `jinja2` says that

```
In most cases it should be more convenient and efficient to use   
the % operator or str.format().
```